# How can I set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin in my spring app on JBoss?

Tags: spring, jboss, cors

I'm running a spring app on JBoss to provide a REST interface to a database.  When my front-end code tries to access the REST app, the request is cancelled because the server is not setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to permit the client to request the data.  How can I set this either on the JBoss server or in the spring application?  One of the controllers is shown below.  I want this REST API to be open to the whole organisation so I just want to set the header to be `'*'`.

```
package com.mycompany.esb.components.controllers;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.hateoas.Resource;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.mycompany.esb.components.ResourceBuilder;
import com.mycompany.esb.jpa.dao.ServicesDAO;
import com.mycompany.esb.jpa.entity.ServicesEntity;

import static org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder.linkTo;
import static org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder.methodOn;

@Controller
@RequestMapping( value = "/services")
public class ServicesController extends BaseController {

    /*
     * Static final values for to limit size of result set
     * for queries where no limits are set
     */
    public static final String DAYS_PREVIOUS = "0.0";
    public static final String HOURS_TO_SHOW = "2.0";

    @Autowired
    private ServicesDAO servicesDAO;
    @Autowired 
    private ResourceBuilder resourceBuilder;

    public void addLinks(List<ServicesEntity> services) {
        resourceBuilder.addServiceLink(this, services);
    }

    public void addLinks(ServicesEntity service) {
        resourceBuilder.addServiceLink(this, service);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "",
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public Resource<List<ServicesEntity>> getAllServices(
            @RequestParam(value = "daysPrevious", defaultValue = DAYS_PREVIOUS) double daysPrevious, 
            @RequestParam(value = "hoursToShow", defaultValue = HOURS_TO_SHOW) double hoursToShow) {

        List<ServicesEntity> services = servicesDAO.getAllServices(daysPrevious, hoursToShow);
        addLinks(services);
        Resource<List<ServicesEntity>> toReturn = new Resource<List<ServicesEntity>>(services);
        toReturn.add(linkTo(methodOn(ServicesController.class).getAllServices(daysPrevious, hoursToShow)).withSelfRel());
        return toReturn;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution worked for me

Put this filter in `web.xml` for my app:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>cors</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.mycompany.components.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>cors</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Add this class to my application, referenced by the filter above:

```
package com.mycompany.components;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class CorsFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, POST, PUT");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I just have a problem with my wildfly server which saying me `HTTP verb was not GET or POST` after an ajax request. Any ideas ?

Comment: Ajax requests usually use an HTTP OPTIONS request first to check whether it is permitted to make the GET/POST call.  It sounds like your server is only permitting GET and POST.  So you'll need to configure it to allow OPTIONS also.  The configuration above sets the allowed methods as follows: `response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, POST, PUT");`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a filter in your Spring app, something like this:

```
@Component
public class CorsFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    if(request.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Method") != null
          && "OPTIONS".equals(request.getMethod())) {
      response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "comma sep list of methods you want to support");
      //additional Access-Control-* like Allow-Headers, Max-Age,...
      ...
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
  }
}
```

and the corresponding [DelegatingFilterProxy](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/DelegatingFilterProxy.html)

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>corsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
```

Comment: I tried this, but it had no effect.  Is there some additional config required that isn't listed in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what helped me! I 've put a class in the default package. for example com.package:

```
package com.package
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

    /**
     * Created by GMiskos on 14/6/2017.
    */
    @Configuration
    public class CORSFilter implements Filter{

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain 
    chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        response.setHeader("access-control-allow-origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, 

     OPTIONS, DELETE, HEAD, PUT");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
            //response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-
     Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, 
     Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, 
     Access-Control-Request-Headers");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

In my web.xml at the end befaure closing tag  (..maybe it's important)

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>cors</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.package.CORSFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>cors</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

and finally i added exactly this dependencies in to my pom.xml

```
<!-- servlet dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
```